# function triggers eventhough without terminator

Tags: php, function

I have this sample functions in php.

```
<?php

        function sample_function($atts)
        {
            echo $atts."<br/>";
        }

        sample_function("James");

        function another_function(){
            echo 'this is another function <br/>';
        }

        another_function()
?>
```

The above code outputs

```
James
this is another function
```

I was expecting some kind of  `syntax error, unexpected end of file` but it did not output error.
My php version is 5.6.15

I was wondering if this is a kind of bug in this php version?
Or I don't know that this is possible in php .Please give some information .Thanks!

Comment: Did you forgot to explain expected results versus actual results?

Comment: I think at the last line in php we don't need semicolon. that's why your function triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing tag of a block of php includes semicolon at the last lines so you don't need to put semicolon there That is why your function automatically triggers, add something after that function line it will not work and tell you there is an error

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that